# Postgres 13 service will not start after installing Postgres 14

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have been using Postgresql 13 on a local server on my Windows 10 computer for over a year successfully now.  I decided to upgrade to 14 yesterday.

I installed 14 on a different port.  I went to go and upgrade as per this command: `pg_upgrade -d "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data" -b "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" -B "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin" -U Postgres`, but it said it cannot connect to the 13 server.  I restarted the computer, and still the 13's Service will not start.

When I type `pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" start` at the cmd line, the below is what shows in my log:

```
2022-02-15 08:53:45.908 +04 [92100] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2022-02-15 08:53:45.909 +04 [92100] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-02-15 08:53:45.910 +04 [92100] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-02-15 08:53:45.954 +04 [92672] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-14 14:08:25 +04
2022-02-15 08:53:45.955 +04 [92672] LOG:  invalid record length at 24/80B400C8: wanted 24, got 0
2022-02-15 08:53:45.955 +04 [92672] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2022-02-15 08:53:45.955 +04 [92672] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2022-02-15 08:53:46.057 +04 [92100] LOG:  startup process (PID 92672) was terminated by exception 0xC0000409
2022-02-15 08:53:46.057 +04 [92100] HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2022-02-15 08:53:46.057 +04 [92100] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2022-02-15 08:53:46.059 +04 [92100] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

What should I do to fix this?

What I have already done is:

1. PostgreSQL.conf - made sure `listen_addresses = '*'` was uncommented
2. made sure Modify was valid for all users of the computer on the Postgres Programs folder
3. I checked that the Postgres user had full rights to the folder, but there was no user found in my windows.
4. I added to the pg_hba file: `#host   all         all         0.0.0.0/0       scram-sha-256`

oh, and in case it's not apparent, I don't know much about Postgres.  I can use it for what I need and that's about it.

Comment: Looks like you have corruption in v13 database.  Make a binary backup of the mess you currently have just in case you need it again, then restore from the last back up.

Answer (score 0):

As JJanes suggested.  I did a backup and then restored in the new server of Postgres 14.  It solved the problem.  Thank you, JJanes.